# Using dynamically allocated matrices

Tags: c++, memory, matrix, allocation

I am currently having trouble to use allocated matrices in C++. I have a variable board that I allocate to be a 8x8 matrix like this:

```
int **board;

board = new int*[8];

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++)
{
   board[i] = new int[8];
}
```

When I try to initialize with 0's right after allocating the matrix, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
   {
       board[i][j] = 0;
   }
}
```

The notation board[i][j] works perfectly. But when I try to use it in another function, it does not work as I would expect. I have used the allocated matrix as a parameter in a function like this:

```
int interpretBoard(int ** board, int ** knightsPos)
{
int k, numKnights = 0;
string buffer;


for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < 8; column++)
    {
       cin >> buffer;

        switch (buffer[0])
        {
            case 'e':
                board[row][column] = 0;
                break;
            case 'b':
                if (buffer[1] == 'n')
                {
                    board[row][column] = 1;
                    knightsPos[0][k] = row;
                    knightsPos[1][k++] = column;
                    numKnights++;
                }
                else
                {
                    board[row][column] = 3;
                }
                break;
            case 'w':
                if (buffer[1] == 'n')
                {
                    board[row][column] = 2;
                    knightsPos[0][k] = row;
                    knightsPos[1][k++] = column;
                    numKnights++;
                }
                else
                {
                    board[row][column] = 4;
                }
                break;
        }

       cout << "board[" << row << "][" << column <<"]: " 
               << board[row][column] << endl;
    }
}

return numKnights;
}
```

I get a segfault when I try to read the matrix like that. I pass the parameter like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int l = 0;
int** board;
int** knightsPos;
vector<int**> boardVector;
vector<int**> knightsPosVector;
vector<int> numKnightsVector;

boardVector[0] = 0;

constructor(board, knightsPos);

while(!cin.eof())
{
    numKnightsVector.push_back(interpretBoard(board,knightsPos));
    boardVector.push_back(board);
    knightsPosVector.push_back(knightsPos);
    l++;
}    

destructor(board,knightsPos);

return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why I can sweep the matrix that way in a portion of the code, but not in another.
I feel that it has something to do with the way I pass the parameter, but I don't understand how it is wrong right now.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Also, use `std::vector`.

Comment: You get a segfault where?

Comment: Post the entire body of `interpretBoard`.

Comment: I posted the entire body of interpretBoard and main. I allocated the matrix in order to use a vector of matrices.

Comment: In `constructor` you initialize a local variable which is lost as soon as the function returns.

Comment: There is honestly no reason for almost (if not every) pointer in this task. [Read this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf), then give serious consideration to how you're doing what you're doing. Also, partial-code will get you likely partial-answers. Without knowing everyplace you can shoot yourself in the foot, the best you can hope from us is speculation-at-best unless the problem is blatant. Ex. We can *guess* what `constructor` looks like, but thats all it would be without *the actual code including declaration.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `int ** board` gives no hint whatsoever about the dimensions you have allocated for your board. So `interpretBoard` doesn't know that it has to work with an 8x8 board.

A alternative is to use a struct that holds the squares of the board, like

```
struct board
{
    int square[8][8];
};
```

Now you have a data type that knows the dimensions, and as a plus you don't need to dynamically allocate anything.

Comment: Strangely enough, using a `int **board` *will work* provided the data passed to it is properly setup. It is fundamentally an unbounded pointer to an array of pointers. The first indirection `board[n]` will get the `n+1`'th pointer from that sequence, followed by the second indirection `board[n][m]`, which will access the `m+1`'th element from there. In other words, this is not the problem. You're correct interpretBoard doesn't know it is an 8x8 board *by declaration*, but it also doesn't *have* to know. (though it seriously should be told via size-parameters to assist the looping limits).